# Why is HTML5 support for capturing camera in mobile browsers only?

Tags: html, camera, getusermedia

The question is not why is mobile important, I get that.

The question is how can it be the case that there is not a single HTML5 browser for the desktop that has these same get user media extensions in place yet??

Basing this on [this post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Comment: What ? You **can** capture the camera from your desktop browser.

Comment: Just go [here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php).

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<video id="video" width="300" height="220" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Take Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="220"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
<Script>
    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = {
                "video": true
            },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
            };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 220);
        });
    }, false);
</Script>
```

that works on both chrome and firefox :)

Answer (score -1):

[Look at this link](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html). This document is not complete. It is subject to major changes and, while early experimentations are encouraged, it is therefore not intended for implementation.

That's why it's not fully supported across browsers.